# Grails 3.0 and Quartz plugin : how do I install it?

Tags: grails, gradle, quartz-scheduler, grails-3.0

If added the following in my build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"}
    }
dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:quartz:1.0.2"
}
```

This could get it to compile.
Although, running

```
grails create-job MyJob
```

results in failure.
I've manually added in grails-app/jobs/MyJob
Triggers doesn't fire, calling MyJob.schedule() results in method not found errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.0'
```

2.0 is the first version of the plugin that Grails 3 supports.

Comment: This works - thanks!. Documentation still needs to be updated though for Grails 3 though.

Comment: How can we see the versions

Comment: @JavaGeek "How can we see the versions" - http://plugins.grails.org/plugins.html#plugin/quartz will generally show the latest version.  You could also view the release tags at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/tags.

Comment: @mvniekerk latest docs can be found here http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/latest/